# Thinking of doing an MBA: Is an $80K top MBA school better than a $24K online MBA school?

Tags: education, tuition

Would I be better off with Rotman, Richard Ivey, Queens, etc. or an online MBA school such as Fredericton?

Answer (score 5):

If you can get into the top school, it's a no-brainer to go that route.  An MBA at a top school will not only give you an education taught by world-renowned professors but also a large network of students and alumni.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The network is definitely a major part of it.  I do agree with you and wanted to get some feedback from others.

Comment: I get the feeling that in the US/Canada its more important about "where" you got the qualification, whereas on this side of the pond I don't think it really matters where you got it, as long as you have one (legitimately of course)

Answer (score 3):

I met two MBA graduates from Harvard - both made VPs at large Canadian companies (i.e. $1B or greater annual revenue) after working 2-5 years as management consultants post-graduation - one is now a divisional president making over $500K in salary along.

When I asked one of them (one that is not yet making $500K in salary) about the Harvard MBA difference, he said the brand-name and the network probably set it apart from others, since most MBA schools now uses the same material as Harvard's.

I tend to agree with his thoughts - I never did felt the caliber of my professor had much to do with my ability to apply what I learn to practical use.  In my own MBA education, the professor did more facilitation than "teaching".  Apparently that is the norm, as MBA is less about being fed information than it is about demonstrating the ability to analyze and present information.

Back to M.Attia's question, I would go with the highest ranked MBA education I could afford (both financially and lifestyle).  A friend of mine was able to get his employer to pay for the $90K tuition fee from Rotman, along with job security for 5 years (not a bad idea in this economy).  I settled for Lansbridge University in Fedricton because the flexibility of distance learning and cost was important to me, though I was able to get my employer to pay for the MBA after I started (I switched group within the company shortly after I started my MBA and my new boss was able to get the approval without locking me in).